# Jquery multi-line text problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, html

I have a div with text inside:

```
<div>A description of dreamstill. It is a music site that is social and other stuff where you cando this and that and pretty much anything that your heart allows. This is probably as long as the description will get.</div>
```

Then I extract the text and stick it as a `data-url` attribute on an image:

```
var desc = div.text();
div.replaceWith('<img class="center" src='+url+' data-desc=' + desc + ' />');
```

The problem is that the image is being generating like this:

```
<img class="center" src="http://featherfiles.aviary.com/2011-09-09/aae3b22a952841cd9c0d6a26a5867325.png" data-desc="A" description="" of="" dreamstill.="" it="" is="" a="" music="" site="" that="" social="" and="" other="" stuff="" where="" you="" cando="" this="" pretty="" much="" anything="" your="" heart="" allows.="" probably="" as="" long="" the="" will="" get.="">
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are missing quotes around the value in the tag, but you can't just add quotes because that will still break if the description text has quotes in it.

Instead, try this.

```
var desc = div.text();
div.replaceWith(
  $('<img />', {
    "class": "center",
    "src": url,
    "data-desc": desc
  })
);
```

Comment: Does this work? I thought the second parameter to the jQuery function was the context element.

Comment: Yep. It was added in 1.4. You can see it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 as "jQuery( html,props )"

Comment: I also need to dynamically wrap the image around `a` tags: `'<a href='+href_url+'><img /></a>'` How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, in that you're missing quotes, but the next problem you'll have will be when a description contains a quote and it breaks the HTML.  My recommendation is to append the image, then set the data-desc.

```
div.replaceWith(
  $('<img class="center" src="' + url + '"/>').attr('data-desc', desc)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.replaceWith('<img class="center" src="'+url+'" data-desc="' + desc + '" />');
```

forgot the " on either side of the `desc`

Comment: This will fail if 'desc' has quotes in it.

Answer (score 1):

You missing quotes. All attributes values should be in **"** quotes

```
div.replaceWith('<img class="center" src='+url+' data-desc="' + desc + '" />');
```

and for url to

```
src="'+url+'"
```

**from w3c**
*Attribute values should always be enclosed in quotes*
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp

**live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/pzC7b/8/

Comment: This will fail if 'desc' has quotes in it.

Comment: one second, I'll try in jsfiddle

Comment: It works on jsfiddle. check if you have all variables like `url` and so on. I've added live demo to the answer

Comment: It semi-works. If you had 'Hey "there' as the description, you're passing jQuery 'data-desc="Hey "there"'. The value of 'data-desc' to the browser is now 'Hey ', which is missing a big chunk of text. For a clearer example, move the 'data-desc' before 'src' and put a quote in. Now the element is entirely missing it's 'src' attribute.

Comment: switch quotes or escape data in your attributes. Use like this `div.replaceWith("<img class='center' src='"+url+"' data-desc='" + desc + "' />');` but in this case you you will have `'` in your sentence you need to escape it http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: Your answer works but has some edge cases is all I really wanted to get across. If you use standard jQuery methods like jimbojw or me, then you don't have to worry about it at all, and it's less likely to break.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace quotes with character entity

```
desc.replace(/\"/g, '&quot;')
```

Result + encode url:

```
div.replaceWith('<img class="center" src="' + encodeURI(url) + '" data-desc="' + desc.replace(/\"/g, '&quot;') + '" />');
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7ufT/)